# RSS with international news and GEO coordinates (GEORSS)

Tags: rss, georss

I'm developing a program who can locate point given a coordinate over a map, do you know an RSS with international news a geo data to test with?

PS: GEODATA EX:

```
GeoRSS-Simple
<georss:point>45.256 -71.92</georss:point>
GeoRSS-GML
  <georss:where>
    <gml:Point>
      <gml:pos>45.256 -71.92</gml:pos>
     </gml:Point>
  </georss:where>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Yahoo! Pipe for a map with news](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=FjNcuFlW3BG43n__GcevXg) includes coordinates in it's RSS feed. Or for testing use the [example feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoRSS#Examples) from the Wikipedia page on GeoRSS.